# ASP.NET button says it can't find the method I put in OnClick

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, onclick, linkbutton

I have a log out button on my main menu and I want it to run a method to log out. However I want to store this method in a separate class as a static method, since this code may be called from other locations too.

Compiler error message:

`CS1061: 'ASP.adminpages_masterpages_adminsystem_master' does not contain a definition for 'ExtensionMethods' and no extension method 'ExtensionMethods' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.adminpages_masterpages_adminsystem_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

My ExtensionMethods class:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void Logout(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               //Logout Code
        }
    }
}
```

My button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="ExtensionMethods.MyExtensionMethods.Logout" Text="Log Out"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the button-click at the code-behind and let that call your static method in other class.

```
    <asp:LinkButton id="button1" runat="server" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click" Text="Log Out"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code-behind:

```
   void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
      ExtensionMethods.MyExtensionMethods.Logout(sender, e);
   }
```

Check the reference for more examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx

Comment: It's not in the codebehind though, it's in a seperate class, so how would it find it?

Comment: @SLC: Ok, I've amended my answer

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this and link it directly, but if there is no other way, I'll do it like this, cheers.

Comment: @SLC: You might be able to do it by wiring up the event-handler for button click, but the wiring have to be done in the code-behind anyhow. So well.... the only alternative might be to create a custom linkbutton and implement your own click handler. Doubt so huh?

Comment: Simple is best, the simplest solution is what I tried, the 2nd simplest is the one you posted, so that's the one I'll use ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler should really be in the page class and not be static. It should be, ideally, protected but it can be public.

Comment: @Kieron: Both you and I misunderstood his question. The function to be triggered is outside the scope of the page. :)